# Text Widget creates a <li>

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar

I've got a basic text widget and, outside the standard `<div class="textwidget">` wrapper there is a `<li id="text-5" class="widget widget_text">` (which I have not added when creating the sidebar in `functions.php` or added when adding a text widget from the dashboard).

i.e. the full code looks like this:

```
<li id="text-5" class="widget widget_text">
  <div class="textwidget">
    <my content>
  </div>
</li>
```

I'm at a loss where this `li` comes from. Any idea why and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: can you show you sidebar.php and the function you're using in your functions.php to create the widget areas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think WordPress widgets create li tags on default.  If you want the bullet points removed you could fix that with a css approach.

```
.widget li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the li tags on default. That was throwing me. After I removed them I didn't need the CSS.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to occur when you leave out `'before_widget'` and `'after_widget'` in the array when you register your sidebar/widget. I had the same problem and fixed it by leaving them blank.

```
register_sidebar( 
    array(  
        'name' => 'Footer Widget',
        'id' => 'footer-widget-1',
        'class' => 'footer-widget',
        'description' => 'Footer widget',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Just logged in to upvote your post :) After 1 hour of banging my head on the wall, I stumbled here! Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a truble with your wordpress theme in file "functions.php" there is a function for creating sidebar, there you have to add this code

```
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="di-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="di-widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3>',
```